# xamarin formsでイメージファイル保存

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

xamarin formsでイメージファイルを保存したいのですが、やり方がわからないので、質問いたします。
ファイルのパスの取得にはPCLStorageを使用し、

```
string FilePath = "/DirectoryDcim";
                  
IFolder Folder = await PCLStorage.FileSystem.Current.GetFolderFromPathAsync(FilePath);
```

と書いています。しかしこの書き方ではFolderはnullになってしまいます。
"/DirectoryDcim"を"/DCIM"としてみてもnullになります。
正しくはどう書けばいいのでしょうか？

また、Folder が正しい値がとれたとして、そこにImageSourceの内容をjpgファイルで保存したいと思っています。
こちらのやり方も、教えていただけると助かります。
参考になるサイトのリンクがあれば張っていただけるとありがたいです。

とりあえずはAndroidのみで動作すれば大丈夫です。

Comment: この辺の記事でしょうか。[DCIMフォルダへのメディアの保存](https://qiita.com/HexagramNM/items/90a0f03e0d3d455d0d40#dcim%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%80%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A1%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%A2%E3%81%AE%E4%BF%9D%E5%AD%98), [Local File Storage Using Xamarin.Forms](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/local-file-storage-using-xamarin-form/), [Xamarin.Forms: How to download an Image, save it locally and display it on screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59632849/9014308), [I am using PCLStorage...](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87498/i-am-using-pclstorage-where-are-the-files-going-to)

Comment: ありがとうございました。試してみます。